# Should i use https request or ajax to send data to clients?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, https

So i'm working on an A/B tester website, similar to http://www.optimizely.com/ and i'm quite new to  web development. An A/B tester pretty much allows clients to create variants of their website to make optimizations based on user response (mouse clicks, etc.). So once the variants are made on our website (e.g. larger button size), my job is to send a package to the client which allows them to access and run the javascripts of the variants on the clients end when their page loads. Do i need an ajax call to send this data or can it be done via https request and what are the pros and cons for what i need done? (We're using mysql, hadoop and php). Thanks.

Comment: I've never heard an HTTPS request and an Ajax request be described as mutually exclusive ...

Comment: It's the same thing (as long as you're on the same domain). One will do a full page redirect, the other will not. The choice is up to you...

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

HTTPS is a communication protocol.  AJAX is a programming pattern (or, perhaps more cynically, buzzword). AJAX most often would use HTTPS to accomplish the actual secure communication between client and server.

Comment: Though it's not really an answer, +1 for echoing my thoughts exactly. The OP seems to have some concepts confused. In a completely unrelated note, I've read that AJAX has now officially become ubiquitous enough to use the informal `Ajax` instead of `AJAX`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you mean....

Depends of what data is being sent - if it is personal data, always use HTTPS calls (ie. request the data from https://yourdomain.com/your_script.php), otherwise HTTP (ie. http://yourdomain.com/your_script.php) will be ok (both of these can be done via ajax, so that's not a problem).